# startEnc function wont accept any object as a parameter

Tags: c++, function, object, parameter-passing

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Encounter.h(5,26): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'TestEnemy'   
Encounter.cpp(10,1): error C2511: 'void Encounter::startEnc(TestEnemy)': overloaded member function not found in 'Encounter'
```

`Hero` and `TestEnemy` are classes I've defined in other h and cpp files

**Encounter.h:**

```
#pragma once
class Encounter
{
public:
    void startEnc(Hero player, TestEnemy e1);
};
```

**Encounter.cpp:**

```
void Encounter::startEnc(Hero player, TestEnemy e1)
{
...
}
```

I suppose the error could be from another part of my code but visual studio seems to suggest that it's something to do with these. I'll share more code if need be; I just didn't want to inflate this post.

Comment: Didn't you forget to `#include` those "other `.hpp`" files?

Comment: I did not! thanks plenty :)